# How to efficiently search specific phrases in Array of words?

Tags: arrays, string, performance, f#

What I need is to look for phrases from array one in array two that contains words. Let`s say Array one contains ["Margaret is a girl"; "Loves";"Potato"; "Swim"], and another is a random text of words that is spit into array. How to efficiently check for phrases(a sequence of words) and just words? 
Because, doing it old fashioned way is going to be timing problem as i think.

Comment: What have you tried and what, specifically, are you struggling with?

Comment: I have tried to sort this problem using FOR loop, and go through the same array a lot of times... And I want to improve it, to shorten needed time

Comment: Your problem is not trivial and requires a non-trivial solution if you need optimal performance. Searching large texts for multiple strings can be implemented efficiently using [prefix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (aka *tries*).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `__.exists` or `__.forall` functions they will shortcircuit as long as a (non-)matching result is found, which will be about as efficient as a for loop:

```
let arr1 = [| "Margaret is a girl"; "Loves";"Potato"; "Swim" |]
let arr2 = [| "Margaret"; "is"; "a"; "girl" |]

let ``can be built from`` words phrase = 
  phrase
  |> String.split ' '
  |> Array.forall (fun word -> words |> Array.contains word)

let buildablePhrases = arr1 |> Array.filter (``can be built from`` arr2)
```

If the arrays are huge and the above code is still too slow, I guess you'll need to start introducing optimizations - remove duplicates, cache most frequent searches, etc. Which optimizations make sense depend on the data you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try to implement your thoughts into my code!